# OpenCV can't draw keypoints

Tags: python, opencv, orb

I tried to run the example code shown for `ORB` in the `openCV` page. First I had to figure out the problem of `cv2.ORB()` (changed to `cv2.ORB_create()`, the after this error, appeared this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "orb.py", line 17, in <module>
    img2 =cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
TypeError: Required argument 'outImage' (pos 3) not found
```

After doing a lot of things shown in blogs and manuals, I decided to add `img` to this function `img2 =cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,img,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)` because of the error in `pos (3)`. It finally worked good, but I'd like to know why only runs like this and no the way the official page states.

BR.

Comment: Please read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the syntax of the `cv2.drawKeypoints()` function, at least for `OpenCV 3.x`.

If you execute `help(cv2.drawKeypoints)` after `import cv2`, you will get below which is self-explanatory.

```
Help on built-in function drawKeypoints:

drawKeypoints(...)
    drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, outImage[, color[, flags]]) -> outImage
```

The `pos(3)` is the output image, `outImage`, to be returned.